# Swift IOS Record Video and Audio with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I was able to successfully grab the recorded video by following this question
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419643/what-am-i-doing-wrong-while-record-video-avfoundation-with-swift)

Basically

1. Inherit from `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate` prototype
2. Loop through available devices
3. Creating a session with the camera
4. Start Recording
5. Stop Recording
6. Get the Record video by implementing above prototype's method

But the file doesn't comes with the audio.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046102/recording-audio-and-video-using-avfoundation-frame-by-frame) question, i have to record audio separately and merge the video and audio using mentioned classes

But i have no idea how to implement video and audio recording at the same time.

```
for device in devices {
    // Make sure this particular device supports video
    if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
        // Finally check the position and confirm we've got the back camera
        if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back) {
            captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
            if captureDevice != nil {
                print("Capture device found")

                beginSession()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in this loop only available device types are .Front and .Back

Answer (score 23):

Following is the way to record **video with audio** using AVFoundation framework.  The steps are:

**1. Prepare the session:**

```
self.captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
```

**2. Prepare available video and audio devices:**

```
let session = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession.init(deviceTypes:[.builtInWideAngleCamera, .builtInMicrophone], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)
        
let cameras = (session.devices.compactMap{$0})
        
for camera in cameras {
    if camera.position == .front {
        self.frontCamera = camera
    }
    if camera.position == .back {
        self.rearCamera = camera

        try camera.lockForConfiguration()
        camera.focusMode = .continuousAutoFocus
        camera.unlockForConfiguration()
    }
}
```

**3. Prepare session inputs:**

```
guard let captureSession = self.captureSession else {
    throw CameraControllerError.captureSessionIsMissing
}

if let rearCamera = self.rearCamera {
    self.rearCameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: rearCamera)
    if captureSession.canAddInput(self.rearCameraInput!) {
        captureSession.addInput(self.rearCameraInput!)
        self.currentCameraPosition = .rear
    } else {
        throw CameraControllerError.inputsAreInvalid
    }
} else if let frontCamera = self.frontCamera {
    self.frontCameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: frontCamera)
    if captureSession.canAddInput(self.frontCameraInput!) {
        captureSession.addInput(self.frontCameraInput!)
        self.currentCameraPosition = .front
    } else {
        throw CameraControllerError.inputsAreInvalid
    }
} else {
    throw CameraControllerError.noCamerasAvailable
}

// Add audio input
if let audioDevice = self.audioDevice {
    self.audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice)
    if captureSession.canAddInput(self.audioInput!) {
        captureSession.addInput(self.audioInput!)
    } else {
        throw CameraControllerError.inputsAreInvalid
    }
}
```

**4. Prepare output:**

```
self.videoOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
if captureSession.canAddOutput(self.videoOutput!) {
    captureSession.addOutput(self.videoOutput!)
}
captureSession.startRunning()
```

**5. Start recording:**

```
func recordVideo(completion: @escaping (URL?, Error?) -> Void) {
    guard let captureSession = self.captureSession, captureSession.isRunning else {
        completion(nil, CameraControllerError.captureSessionIsMissing)
        return
    }
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let fileUrl = paths[0].appendingPathComponent("output.mp4")
    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileUrl)
    videoOutput!.startRecording(to: fileUrl, recordingDelegate: self)
    self.videoRecordCompletionBlock = completion
}
```

**6. Stop recording:**

```
func stopRecording(completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    guard let captureSession = self.captureSession, captureSession.isRunning else {
        completion(CameraControllerError.captureSessionIsMissing)
        return
    }
    self.videoOutput?.stopRecording()
}
```

**7. Implement the delegate:**

```
func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
    if error == nil {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I took idea from here: https://www.appcoda.com/avfoundation-swift-guide/

Here is the complete project https://github.com/rubaiyat6370/iOS-Tutorial/

Comment: It is worth mentioning that you have to add permission for "Privacy - Camera Usage Description", and "Privacy - Microphone Usage Description" to your info.plist.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer, This answer goes with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419643/what-am-i-doing-wrong-while-record-video-avfoundation-with-swift) code

It can simply done by

1. declare another capture device variable
2. loop through devices and initialize camera and audio capture device variable
3. add audio input to session

**code**

```
var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?
var captureAudio :AVCaptureDevice?
```

**Loop through devices and Initialize capture devices**

```
var captureDeviceVideoFound: Bool = false
var captureDeviceAudioFound:Bool = false

// Loop through all the capture devices on this phone
for device in devices {
// Make sure this particular device supports video
    if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
// Finally check the position and confirm we've got the front camera
        if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front) {

            captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice //initialize video
            if captureDevice != nil {
                print("Capture device found")
                captureDeviceVideoFound = true; 
            }
        }
    }
    if(device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)){
        print("Capture device audio init")
        captureAudio = device as? AVCaptureDevice //initialize audio
        captureDeviceAudioFound = true
    }
}
if(captureDeviceAudioFound && captureDeviceVideoFound){
    beginSession() 
}
```

**Inside Session**

```
try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureAudio))
```

This will output the video file with audio. no need to merge audio or do anything.

This apples documentation [helps](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html)

Answer (score 2):

Followed the answer from @Mumu but it didn't work for me because of the call to AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession.init that was returning video devices only.

Here is my version that works on iOS 14, Swift 5:

```
var captureSession: AVCaptureSession? = nil
var camera: AVCaptureDevice? = nil
var microphone: AVCaptureDevice? = nil
var videoOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput? = nil
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer? = nil

func findDevices() {
    camera = nil
    microphone = nil

    //Search for video media type and we need back camera only
    let session = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession.init(deviceTypes:[.builtInWideAngleCamera],
            mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.back)
    var devices = (session.devices.compactMap{$0})
    //Search for microphone
    let asession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession.init(deviceTypes:[.builtInMicrophone],
            mediaType: AVMediaType.audio, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)
    //Combine all devices into one list
    devices.append(contentsOf: asession.devices.compactMap{$0})
    for device in devices {
        if device.position == .back {
            do {
                try device.lockForConfiguration()
                device.focusMode = .continuousAutoFocus
                device.flashMode = .off
                device.whiteBalanceMode = .continuousAutoWhiteBalance
                device.unlockForConfiguration()
                camera = device
            } catch {
            }
        }
        if device.hasMediaType(.audio) {
            microphone = device
        }
    }
}

func initVideoRecorder()->Bool {
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    guard let captureSession = captureSession else {return false}

    captureSession.sessionPreset = .hd4K3840x2160
    findDevices()

    guard let camera = camera else { return false}
    do {
        let cameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera)
        captureSession.addInput(cameraInput)
    } catch {
        self.camera = nil
        return false
    }

    if let audio = microphone {
        do {
            let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audio)
            captureSession.addInput(audioInput)
        } catch {
        }
    }

    videoOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput!) {
        captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput!)
        captureSession.startRunning()
        videoOutput?.connection(with: .video)?.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer?.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
        previewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
        return true
    }

    return false
}

func startRecording()->Bool {
    guard let captureSession = captureSession, captureSession.isRunning else {return false}
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let fileUrl = paths[0].appendingPathComponent(getVideoName())
    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileUrl)
    videoOutput?.startRecording(to: fileUrl, recordingDelegate: self)
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem also, but when I grouped adding the video input and the sound input after, the audio worked. This is my code for adding the inputs.

```
if (cameraSession.canAddInput(deviceInput) == true && cameraSession.canAddInput(audioDeviceInput) == true) {//detects if devices can be added
    cameraSession.addInput(deviceInput)//adds video
    cameraSession.addInput(audioDeviceInput)//adds audio
}
```

Also I found you have to have video input first or else there won't be audio. I originally had them in two if statements, but I found putting them in one lets video and audio be recorded together. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Record Video With Audio**

//Get Video Device

```
if let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) as? [AVCaptureDevice] {
    for device in devices {
        if device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back {
                videoCaptureDevice = device
            }
        }
    }
    if videoCaptureDevice != nil {
        do {
            // Add Video Input
            try self.captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice))
            // Get Audio Device
            let audioInput = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)
            //Add Audio Input
            try self.captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioInput))
            self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)
            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
            self.videoView.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
            //Add File Output
            self.captureSession.addOutput(self.movieOutput)
            captureSession.startRunning()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

For more details refer this link:

https://medium.com/@santhosh3386/ios-avcapturesession-record-video-with-audio-23c8f8c9a8f8